# verifyMessage throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined`

Tags: ethers.js

I'm implementing web3 authentication using sign message and verify message. On my client side i have following code:

```
 const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  const message = `Current time ${timestamp}`
  const signedMessage = await signer.signer.signMessage(message)
  
  await axios.post(`${config.BACKEND_URL}/inventory/verify`, {
    message,
    address, signedMessage
  })
```

And on my backend i'm executing:

```
public async verify(data) {
   const { message, address, signature } = data;

   const _address = utils.verifyMessage(message, signature)
}
```

but when `util.verifyMessage` get called i receive this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined` any idea why it's happening? First time doing these operations sorry ;s